# Const array and pointer to const

Tags: c, c99

I just had a strange error on an old compiler (ColdFire 5703 MCCCF) and I want to confirm I understood correctly the C standard relative to pointer to const and const arrays (let's say in C99 even if this compiler is older).

Say I have this function:

```
void func(const unsigned char *cst_ptr);
```

and the array:

```
const unsigned char array[xx] = {...};
```

So `array` is an array where every element is `const`.

Then if I do:

```
func(array)
```

then `array` is equivalent to `&array[0]` so the object passed in parameter is of type `const unsigned char *` hence the prototype of the function is respected.

Is it correct ?

Comment: In almost all use cases `array` decays to a pointer to its first element. So, whenever (except for the few exceptions) you use `array`, you are using a `const unsigned char *`. So your code is correct, but not because of your reason.

Comment: What error you have?

Comment: Only `&arr`,`sizeof arr` and `_Alignof arr` behaves differently. In all other context pointer and array are equivalent

Comment: @0___________ error like "pointer to const becomes unrestricted" but I don't have the exact sentence available. My question was more generic, about the difference between const array and pointer to const

Comment: @mch what do you mean by "not because of your reason". Aren't we saying the same thing ?

Comment: Everything you say is correct. Notably, it doesn't even matter if the data in the caller is `const` qualified or not, since a pointer-to-const-data can be assigned to a pointer-to-data (but not the other way around). None of this is specific to C99, it's all the same no matter C version. What compiler are you using? I would guess Codewarrior(?) but that one got decent (C90) standard compliance so it wouldn't give the error you describe.

Comment: @Lundin the compiler is MCCCF, a compiler for an old Coldfire

Answer (score 2):

`const unsigned char *cst_ptr` it is not a const pointer only the pointer to `const unsigned char`.

When you use the array as a parameter of the function, the array decays to a pointer to fist element of the array. If the array was declared as having `const unsigned char` elements it will match your function declaration.

OT:

The const pointer is declared another way:

```
unsigned char * const const_ptr;
```

if you want const pointer to const data:

```
const unsigned char * const const_ptr;
```

Comment: yes it was a typo, I was referring to pointer to const. Edited

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you are right, the type of the object passed as a parameter is `const char *`, because the whole var type is conserned by the `const`. so you gonna have something like `cst_ptr = {[B][o][o][M][!]}` that can't be changed by the futur.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: what is `cst_ptr = {[B][o][o][M][!]}`?

Comment: It can be something like that*